# Draw2D Set Position

Tags: javascript, draw2d-js

I am new to this library and cannot seem to find anything that gives good detail on how to size and position the canvas. Hopefully someone here can direct me in the best way of positioning the canvas

```
   $(window).load(function () {


    // create the canvas for the user interaction
    //
    var canvas = new draw2d.Canvas("gfx_holder");

    // unmarshal the JSON document into the canvas
    // (load)
    var reader = new draw2d.io.json.Reader();
    reader.unmarshal(canvas, jsonDocument);

    // display the JSON document in the preview DIV
    //
    displayJSON(canvas);

    // add an event listener to the Canvas for change notifications.
    // We just dump the current canvas document into the DIV
    //
    canvas.getCommandStack().addEventListener(function (e) {
        if (e.isPostChangeEvent()) {
            displayJSON(canvas);
        }
    });
});

function displayJSON(canvas) {
    var writer = new draw2d.io.json.Writer();
    writer.marshal(canvas, function (json) {
        $("#json").text(JSON.stringify(json, null, 2));
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"gfx_holder" is the id of your HTML element.  You can set the width and height using regular JavaScript.